# Is Process Builder is replacement for Flow or Workflow Rule?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

Can i use Process Builder in place of Visual Flow or we can use it only for trigger and Workflow Rule.

Comment: The process builder replaced what salesforce was calling "flow trigger workflow actions".

Comment: kumar that's a very broad question, which includes very little information on what type of requirements/criteria should be considered for an answer. The different features have a few different unique use cases. Please also use relevant tags do the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process Builder is designed to supersede Flow Triggers, but does not inherently replace a Flow that has Screen elements (there's no way to build a "screen" in Process Builder). You can use Process Builder in place of a Flow that is designed to act as a trigger or Workflow Rule.